# c # application / solution in NET 3.5 but needed reference NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

I have a c# application / solution ( only few classes and files) which is NET 3.5. So under target framework you see 3.5.

But 1 reference (System.Xaml) is from NET 4.0.

And i am not allowed to switch the whole solution to NET 4.0. How can i use System.Xaml (4.0) within a solution targeting 3.5?

edit:
Is it possible to have within 1 solution 2 projects, where one targets NET 3.5 and the other targets 4.0. the point is that within the 3.5 project some other application is "started" which accepts only 3.5

Comment: is it actually using new functionality from the 4.0 framework? otherwise -> remove 4.0 reference, add 3.5 Reference

Comment: System.Xaml is only in 4.0 and 4.5 NET Framework

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. It operates on a newer CLR.

Comment: thats what i thought too and explained to original creater of the code... Is it possible to have within 1 solution 2 projects, where one targets NET 3.5 and the other targets 4.0. the point is that within the 3.5 project some other application is "started" which accepts only 3.5

Comment: if the 3.5 project is the exe, then no.